# A more efficient 'remove keywords' function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Previously, I asked about making a 'remove duplicates' function more efficient.  I was kindly helped by Jordan Runner and elsewhere by Ed Nelson, and the resulting code made a massive positive impact on my work.  I have a 'remove keywords' function, too, that runs finely for sheets with less than 1,500 rows.  But anything bigger and it takes forever and sometimes bumps into the 'Exceeded maximum execution time'.

If there are two or three keywords, even my code works finely.  Yet I have about 1,000 keywords that I need to remove from sheets that sometimes exceed 20,000 rows (2 columns).  With such large sheets, my code is not fit for purpose and I resort to breaking down my sheet into 2k pieces.  Can someone help make the code operable for even large sheets of ~20,000 rows and with sets of 1,000 keywords that need to be removed?

```
function removeKeywords() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var rowsDeleted = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];

    if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword1") > -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }

    if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword2") > -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }

    if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword3") > -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
}
```

As noted elsewhere, I'm self-taught.

Comment: This is actually a really tricky problem. Do you need to match the keyword anywhere in the cell, or does it have to be an exact match (e.g. does `hello world` match the keyword `hello`)?

Comment: The former, i.e., if "democ" is a targeted keyword, then all cells containing words such as "democracy" and "democratic" need to be removed.  This is how the function works at the moment and I would like to retain that useful feature.

Comment: Yeah, that's a really tricky thing, because the complexity adds up very quickly. Your code, which is a reasonable approach, has a time complexity *O*(*n*×*m*×*x*), *n* is the number of rows, *m* is the number for keywords, and *x* is the complexity of searching for a keyword in a cell (which depends on the search algorithm used by `indexOf` and the length of the keyword and the length of the search text).

Comment: Okay, so I should stick to my method of breaking up large sheets into smaller ones.  Would a faster processor be able to beat Google Spreadsheet's timeout error?

Comment: If you can’t find another solution, I would stick to that method or change the function to accept a range of cells, then call it multiple times in one sheet (you could have automatically select the next range after each run, which would make it a lot less tedious). A faster processor won’t help you because Apps Scripts run on Google’s servers, not your computer.

Comment: @JordanRunning, thanks for taking the time to respond.  I wonder whether you can show me how to write a script that would generate a list of keywords that have been deleted by my function.  I ask because Tanaike (below) has kindly produced a modified function, yet in my tests, the number of keywords deleted by the modified script and my original script differs.  So I thought it would be well to compare the list of deleted keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the solution of your question yet? If you are doing, how about this sample script? The modification points are as follows.

#### Modification points :

- `deleteRow()` was achieved by overwriting using data which reflected the searched results, because the cost of `deleteRow()` is high.
- Array was used to search keywords.

#### Modified script :

```
function removeKeywords() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var keywords = ["keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"]; // Please set keywords here.
  var resValues = [];
  for (var i in values) {
    if (keywords.filter(function(e){return ~values[i][0].indexOf(e)}).length == 0) {
      resValues.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  var res = [];
  resValues.forEach(function(e1, i1) {
    var temp = [];
    e1.forEach(function(e2, i2) {
      temp.push(formulas[i1][i2] ? formulas[i1][i2] : e2);
    });
    res.push(temp);
  });
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Note :

- When you use this sample script, please prepare a sample spreadsheet and run this. Or please use the copied Spreadsheet.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

```
function removeKeywords() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var keywords = ["keyword1", "keyword2", "keyword3"]; // Please set keywords here.
  var resValues = [];
  var removedRows = [];
  for (var i in values) {
    if (keywords.filter(function(e){return ~values[i][0].indexOf(e)}).length == 0) {
      resValues.push(values[i]);
    } else {
      removedRows.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  var res = [];
  resValues.forEach(function(e1, i1) {
    var temp = [];
    e1.forEach(function(e2, i2) {
      temp.push(formulas[i1][i2] ? formulas[i1][i2] : e2);
    });
    res.push(temp);
  });
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
  Logger.log(res)
  Logger.log(removedRows) // Removed rows
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tanaike.  I ran tests on columns with 3,000 entries and 5,000 entries as below:

Entries: 3,000

Original Function
Time: 1m3s
Final count: 2757

Modified Function
Time: 25s
Final count: 2842

Entries: 5,000

Original Function
Time: 2m27s
Final count: 4488

Modified Function
Time: 43s
Final count: 4703

Comment: Apologies, I am not sure how to format correctly in comments.  What is puzzling, in any case, is that the original function removes more keywords.  Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: is there a way to tell which script is more accurate in its removal of keywords (besides manually checking)?  I am puzzled as to why the number of keywords removed between my original script and your modified script is different.

Comment: For example, is there a way to generate a list comprising deleted keywords?

Comment: @Ed Dev I'm sorry for the inconvenience. At first, can I confirm what you want to do? From your question, I understand that you want to remove rows that keywords were included in the column A. Each value of column A is searched by some keywords. If the value includes one of keywords, delete the row. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify. And I updated my answer. "list comprising deleted keywords" is shown as ``removedRows``. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you, @Tanaike.  Can you please let me know how I can create a list of the removed keywords and display them in Column C?

Comment: In the Scripts window, View > Logs provides me with a list of values from the column that contained the keywords.  Yet the removed keywords are not displayed / logged.

Comment: I was hoping to generate a report like the following for this function, plus a list of deleted keywords:

``// Show summary
      const secs = (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(
        Utilities.formatString('Processed %d rows in %.2f seconds (%.1f rows/sec); %d deleted',
                               numRows, secs, numRows / secs, numRows - 
    newData.length),
        'Remove keywords', -1);
    }``

Comment: @Ed Dev I'm sorry for the inconvenience because of my incomplete answer. I cannot understand your current situation. In order to clear it, can you update your question with the detail information what you want to do and show us a sample data? And if you want to import ``removedRows`` to column C, you can use ``sheet.getRange(1, 3, removedRows.length, removedRows[0].length).setValues(removedRows);``

Comment: Thank you very much, @Tanaike.  That solved my problem.

Comment: Hello again, @Tanaike.  Could you please let me know how I can make sure that with your script duplicates are removed regardless of whether they are lower or upper case?

Comment: @Ed Dev I'm sorry. I couldn't understand your situation. So can you post the next question as a new question? At that time, when you add the detail information about it, it will help users including me to think of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make asynchronous functions or you could make use of WebWorkers. Check how to use WebWorkers here: [Using web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Now, I can give you an example without WebWorkers, and that's using the `setTimeout()` function in javascript.

```
function removeKeywords() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();
    var rowsDeleted = 0;


    var i = 0;

    function deleteRows() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (i <= numRows) {
                var row = values[i];

                if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword1") > -1) {
                    sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
                    rowsDeleted++;
                }

                if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword2") > -1) {
                    sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
                    rowsDeleted++;
                }

                if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword3") > -1) {
                    sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
                    rowsDeleted++;
                }

                i += 1;
                deleteRows();
            }
        }, 25);
    }

    deleteRows();
}
```

Of course, that's going to be slower than by using web workers, but at least it won't block your browser.

More info on `setTimeout()` [here](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval)

Comment: That returns the following error: Missing ; before statement. (line 9, file "Copy of Code")

Comment: Please try using `var` instead of `let`

Comment: Thanks, Sergiu.  But now I get:  Syntax error. (line 11, file "Copy of Code")

Comment: I've edited my original answer. By the way, what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox (not Opera, sorry).  Is that problematic?

Comment: If you're still learning then it's not. But I recommend you switch to the latest version of Chrome or Firefox .

Comment: I'm still getting the following with the edited code: Missing ; before statement. (line 9, ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163908/discussion-between-sergiu-and-ed-dev).

Comment: Just an update here in case others are following.  The answer given above by @Sergiu doesn't quite work in Google Spreadsheets.  If anyone else can instruct, that would be much appreciated.  @JordanRunner?

Comment: @Sergiu Google Apps Script code runs on the server, so no WebWorker. And making the code asynchronous will make the function return faster, but it won’t make the complete operation take any less time.

Comment: Hello @JordanRunning I wasn't aware that this is google apps script. Now, I remain curios. What is the solution here?